# Use Net::ssh to open a tunnel and then ssh to a second device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ssh

I think I may want a multi-hop SSH tunnel.
I already have the ssh to the first device working with the following code.

```
    def ssh
    Net::SSH.start("#{self.ssh_host}", "#{self.ssh_user}", { port: self.ssh_port, password: "#{self.ssh_pass}" } ) do |ssh|
      ssh.exec! @script
    end
  end
```

Now what I need to do is to leave the first connection open and then ssh to a second device on the same LAN as the first device. The idea here is to tunnel to one device and then ssh out to all of the network gear on that LAN and talk to it. I need to set the ssh username and password in the command and then run a command.

Comment: Do u wish to execute another ssh.exec within ssh.exec ?

Comment: @Shishir yes i do. Ssh to a probe at a site and then tunnel to many devices behind that device.